# Search results on google image search shows slider images

Tags: search, google-analytics, seo, robots.txt, google-search-console

[image]

Is there any way to disallow slider images on google search results ? I heard that making robots.txt will fix this problem.

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /images/abc.jpg
```

: this is for a perticular image. and I want to disallow a whole image directory

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /images/
```

: is it possible to make something like this ? will it affect the existing search result ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Asking how a search engine will display/rank/parse your site is off topic. It may be more suitable on Webmasters SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use your 2nd variant. After some time, these restricted images will dissapear from image search, since Google will remove it from the index due to *robots.txt* restriction. Don't forget to add/test new *robots.txt* to your Google Webmaster Tools account.